# Mocking multiple calls

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using ts-mock-imports and I want to mock multiple return values of a function call, then check that a function was called a given number of times.  The following works:

```
    const getUserSpy = dataServiceMock.mock('getUserFromDB')
                                      .returns({...USER_1})
                                      .returns({...USER_2});
```

In my test case, I have two calls to getUserFromDB() and with the above, getUserSpy.callCount is equal to 2.  But this is order-dependent, so I'd rather be able to do the following:

```
    const getUser1Spy = dataServiceMock.mock('getUserFromDB')
                                      .withArgs(USER_1_ID).returns({...USER_1});
    const getUser2Spy = dataServiceMock.mock('getUserFromDB')
                                      .withArgs(USER_2_ID).returns({...USER_2});
```

What I would expect is that getUser1Spy is called once, and getUser2Spy is called once.  However, it looks like the second call to withArgs() removes the previous instance of mocking.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
const getUserSpy = dataServiceMock.mock('getUserFromDB');
getUserSpy.withArgs(USER_1_ID).returns({...USER_1});
getUserSpy.withArgs(USER_2_ID).returns({...USER_2});

// ... then ...

assert(getUserSpy.callCount).equals(2);
```